# Ubuntu 20.4.3 & Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS Network Cable Issues

Tags: networking, ethernet

First I want to Thank you I am much apricate this website and the help of you all, without you I think I didn't know ubuntu at all.

My issue is this:

I have downloaded the ISO of LTS from the official website I came across an issue that is persist for both of the LTS's versions 3 and 4.
I install the 20.04.3 LTS on Asus ROG G14 and had the network issue fixed it with change netplan to Network manager. Also came across this on a PC that's build by my company basic as they come and same issue on Ubuntu 20.4.3 LTS after change to network-manger no issue at all Wifi and LAN working.

now I need to set up the Ubuntu 20.4.4 LTS and the issue is persist here also..

only wifi no Ethernet cable I have the issue that on
lshw -C network
LAN show as unclaimed
not recognize on ip a or ifconfig at all..
changed to NetWork-manger as usual  but still not helping...
now again no matter which PC or Laptop 20.4.4 LTS only have wifi's now tests on Dell XPS's and latitude also on ROG and on our build PC's same to all only Wifi is shown..

I mention at the beginning that I download form the official Ubuntu website last time changing the ISO image to 20.4.4 was actually the solution...
also format and reinstall ubuntu didn't helped.
( I tried a **lot** of manuals none of them helped I will glad try everything you suggest except 22.04 LTs)
Fire away and sending all of you a hug because each and one of you helped at lease one time :)

Comment: to be clear: wifi works but ethernet doesn't? can you post the output of `sudo lshw -C network` and `lspci`?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you trying to get wifi or ethernet going? Are you trying to fix  Dell XPS's and latitude also on ROG? Which? The solution is likely to be quite different on all of these machines as the hardware is likely quite different. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: thank you for the fast replay,
Wifi is working- Ethernet cable not working - USB adapter to RJ working- physical cable not identify adding data :
https://ibb.co/n7ykbLt - sudo lshw -C network
https://ibb.co/Jz7sJR1 - lspci

Comment: Please let us see the exact response to: `sudo modprobe e1000e` Thanks.

Comment: Hello all fount the issue was BIOS update the system is OK thank you fir the quick support :)